# How to position the text to be in the middle of the top border of a table using css

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-position

I have a table and now I need to position a piece of text on the top border of it.
To look like:
[Desired Text positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q5Aj.png)
Also to make it be resizable in a window as I have tried positioning it but it keeps moving around also when I use %'s.
I have tried multiple things such as basic positioning like top, left. Also fixed positioning but every time I line it up specifically then change the size of the window it changes the size/position of the text and the background.

The html file is here html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Exercise 4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/exercise4.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        <h4>Shirt order form</h4>
    </header>
    <table>
        <!-- <tr>
            <th>Shirt order form</th>
        </tr> -->
        <form method="GET" action="http://webprojects.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/un300/week4/week4_process.php">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="container">
                        <label for="choice">Shirt size</label>
                    </div>
                    <select name="choices">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose size</option>
                        <option>XS</option>
                        <option>S</option>
                        <option>M</option>
                        <option>L</option>
                        <option>XL</option>
                    </select>
                    
                    <div class="container">
                        <label for="radio">Sleeves</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="radio" name="Sleeves" value="1" checked>Short</br>
                    <input type="radio" name="Sleeves" value="2">Long
                    <h4>Choose a colour</h4>
                    <input type="color" name="colorChoice">

                    <h4>Quantity</h4>
                    <input type="number" min="1" max="10" name="Quantity" >

                    <h4>Date Requested </h4>
                    <input type="date">
                </td>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="container">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                    </div>
                        <input type="name">
                    
                    <div class="container">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                        <input type="email" required>
                    
                
                    <div class="container">
                        <label for="Telephone" >Telephone</label>
                    </div>
                    <section id="right">
                        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="^\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" required>
                        <p>Example: 44-207-882-1234</p>
                    </section>
                </td>

            </tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="container">
                        <label for="address">Address</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="address">
                    <div class="container">
                        <label for="city">City</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="city" list="cities">
                    <datalist id="cities">
                        <option>London</option>
                        <option>Paris</option>
                        <option>Hong Kong</option>
                        <option>Scotland</option>
                    </datalist>
                    <div class="container">
                        <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="postcode">

                </td>
            <footer id="footer">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <footer id="footer">
                        <label for="checkbox">Please keep me informed about future shirt designs</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                        <div class="formRow space">
                            <input type="submit">
                            <input type="reset">
                        </div>

                        <p>&copy; 2023 Shirt Order Form</p>
                        
                        </footer>
                    </td>
                    
                </tr>
            










        </form>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The css file is here css:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    width: 75%;
    background-color: rgb(121, 204, 121);
    margin-top: 5vh;
}

.formRow {
    /* display: table-row; */
    display: flex; /* Set the formRow element to use flexbox */
    justify-content: center; /* Center the child elements horizontally */
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    

}

#right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    
}

#right p {
    margin-left: 3.6%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
   
}

/* td {
    white-space: nowrap;
  } */

.space {
    margin-top: 10%;
    /* margin-bottom: 5%; */
}

input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Change the background color */
    color: white; /* Change the font color */
    padding: 12px 24px;
    font-size: 16px; /* Set the font size */
    cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer cursor on hover */
    border-radius: 5px;

    margin: 25px;
    
  }

  input[type="reset"] {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Change the background color */
    color: white; /* Change the font color */
    padding: 12px 24px;
    font-size: 16px; /* Set the font size */
    cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer cursor on hover */
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    margin: 25px;
  }


body {
    max-width: 800px;   
    margin: auto;
    

}

#footer {
    background-color: white;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    
    
}



header {
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 32px;
    left: 120px; */
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    /* margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%; */
    border: blue;
    height: 5vh;
  }

/* th {
    
    background-color: green;
} */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<caption>`element and style it as needed - see below. This is also the semantically recommended way, for example by MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Styling_tables

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: rgb(121, 204, 121);
  margin-top: 5vh;
}
caption {
  background: #fa0;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 4px;
}


.formRow {
  /* display: table-row; */
  display: flex;
  /* Set the formRow element to use flexbox */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Center the child elements horizontally */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#right p {
  margin-left: 3.6%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}


/* td {
    white-space: nowrap;
  } */

.space {
  margin-top: 10%;
  /* margin-bottom: 5%; */
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Change the background color */
  color: white;
  /* Change the font color */
  padding: 12px 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Set the font size */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Add a pointer cursor on hover */
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 25px;
}

input[type="reset"] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Change the background color */
  color: white;
  /* Change the font color */
  padding: 12px 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Set the font size */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Add a pointer cursor on hover */
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 25px;
}

body {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

#footer {
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 32px;
    left: 120px; */
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  /* margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%; */
  border: blue;
  height: 5vh;
}


/* th {
    
    background-color: green;
} */
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Shirt order form</caption>
  <form method="GET" action="http://webprojects.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/un300/week4/week4_process.php">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <label for="choice">Shirt size</label>
        </div>
        <select name="choices">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose size</option>
          <option>XS</option>
          <option>S</option>
          <option>M</option>
          <option>L</option>
          <option>XL</option>
        </select>

        <div class="container">
          <label for="radio">Sleeves</label>
        </div>
        <input type="radio" name="Sleeves" value="1" checked>Short</br>
        <input type="radio" name="Sleeves" value="2">Long
        <h4>Choose a colour</h4>
        <input type="color" name="colorChoice">

        <h4>Quantity</h4>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="10" name="Quantity">

        <h4>Date Requested </h4>
        <input type="date">
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <input type="name">

        <div class="container">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <input type="email" required>


        <div class="container">
          <label for="Telephone">Telephone</label>
        </div>
        <section id="right">
          <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="^\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" required>
          <p>Example: 44-207-882-1234</p>
        </section>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <td>
      <div class="container">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="address">
      <div class="container">
        <label for="city">City</label>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="city" list="cities">
      <datalist id="cities">
                        <option>London</option>
                        <option>Paris</option>
                        <option>Hong Kong</option>
                        <option>Scotland</option>
                    </datalist>
      <div class="container">
        <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="postcode">

    </td>
    <footer id="footer">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <footer id="footer">
            <label for="checkbox">Please keep me informed about future shirt designs</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

            <div class="formRow space">
              <input type="submit">
              <input type="reset">
            </div>

            <p>&copy; 2023 Shirt Order Form</p>

          </footer>
        </td>

      </tr>











  </form>
</table>
```